# RandomForest for Big Data

Tags: python, hadoop, random-forest, kaggle

I'm working with big data of over 4 million records where I want to predict 3 labels based on 9 variables. I used RandomForest but it takes several hours and I am wondering if there is someway I can include Hadoop in my code to improve time.

Notes:
I use Kaggle notebook with session quota of:
12 hours max
30 g ram max

Comment: Try LightGBM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightGBM

Comment: Have you limited the depth parameters and also set `n_jobs = -1` to use all available processors?

Comment: You can try PySpark or Polars. You dont need "Hadoop"

Comment: @Sean Do you have a sample code of how the limitation is done?

Answer (score 1):

Before using Hadoop, let's clear what it provides and do you need that.

Hadoop is a tech stack provides distributed file system (HDFS), resource negotiator for distributed processing (YARN) and MapReduce framework.

It is useful when you want to make your computing distributed and resolve your problem faster using more resources. But it maybe an overkill to create hadoop cluster for your task.

You can use  Spark and [RandomForestClassifier](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.html). Spark is an inmemory distributed computing engine with good support of ML algorithms.

Spark can be running with Hadoop but it is not a strict requirement. You can run Spark also in Standalone mode or with Mesos or Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you Egor! I used spark with RandomForest and there is a significant improvement in the processing time. However, I'm not able to predict the three labels at once and I had to do three models each for one label. Do you think there is a way we can achieve this in one step?

Comment: According to documentation, RandomForestClassifier supports multiclass labels. See this, I hope it will be useful
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier